# My hp 250 g4 shuts down in installation

Tags: shutdown, nomodeset

hi all i am new to Ubuntu

i want to install Ubuntu  in my laptop hp 250 but it always shuts down in the first seconds and not installing

i searched in the net and installed it with `nomodeset`

my question is what is `nomodeset` and is it normal to install Ubuntu using this option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[nomodeset](https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/nomodeset.html) is commonly used during or after installation. It tells the kernel not to load any video drivers until after the kernel is fully loaded and running.

To make the change permanent, run `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`. 
Find the *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=* line and replace **quiet** with **nomodeset** .

Save it, exit and then run `sudo update-grub` to make the change permanent. See https://www.howtogeek.com/196655/how-to-configure-the-grub2-boot-loaders-settings/ for  more details.

Note: [Most HP 250 G4](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04605376#AbT1) machines use Intel HD Graphics which have their drivers already in the kernel. However, at least one model has an AMD Radeon R5 M330 graphics processor which would require a specific driver; either the [Open Source drivers](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux), or the [proprietary AMD driver](https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/linux/amdgpu-pro-19.30-855429-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz).

This depends on the exact model number of your machine, which is on the underside of the laptop on the sticker which also has your serial number. Once you have it, go to [HP 250 G4 support](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-250-g4-notebook-pc/7609933), enter your model or serial number, and then go to Specifications to see which graphics you have.

Comment: thank you for answering, but now i have to set ```nomodeset``` on every boot is there a work around

Comment: @med morad Answer amended to provide more detail.